# How do i get billing address into Authorize.net sdk for php?

Tags: php, api, sdk, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am trying to set up authorize.net's SDK for php and I am having trouble getting the billing address to work properly. I checked the sample on GitHub and I am able to get transactions to go through to my sandbox account but I don't know how to get the billing info to show up. Please keep in mind I am no php wiz so please don't assume things if there is a deeper explanation.

Here is the code...

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");

// Common setup for API credentials
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
$merchantAuthentication->setName("My api login");
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("my api key");

// Create the payment data for a credit card
$creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
$creditCard->setCardNumber("6011000000000012");
$creditCard->setExpirationDate("2038-12");
$paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
$paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);


// Create a transaction
$transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
$transactionRequestType->setTransactionType( "authCaptureTransaction"); 
$transactionRequestType->setAmount(9.51);
$transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);

//Billing Address
$billTo = new AnetAPI\billToType();
$billTo->setfirstName("Jordan");
$billTo->setlastName("Smith");
$billTo->setaddress("381 Indian Ave");
$billTo->setcity("Bridgeport");
$billTo->setstate("CT");
$billTo->setzip("06606");
$billTo->setcountry("USA");


$request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
$request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
$request->setTransactionRequest( $transactionRequestType);
$controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

if ($response != null)
{
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

    if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()=="1") )   
    {
        echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
        echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo  "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Here is a picture of the transaction details...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nJyA.png)

Comment: This is all random info. No one's credit card information was harmed lol

Comment: So for test transactions that you did a day or more ago - you can go into the sandbox account - then on the left go to search for transactions - search by batch - are you seeing your test transactions there? if yes, click on the 'trans id' for a specific transaction - and that will bring up the full report that includes the billing info.

Comment: Please take a look at the picture. I see the transaction and it has been processed but i cant get the billing info to process in the transaction as well. Thanks for your time though

Comment: solved*********check out https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/547daabc90ff0f579530d6e5295c02d52e27b257/PaymentTransactions/charge-credit-card.php. I didnt think the actual github page for charge-credit-card.php would be different than the example provided intially on the authorize.net php github home page.

Comment: Cool yeah i see the the line here to include it as part of the transaction   $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto); And wow i had not looked at the authorize dev pages in a while - i know they are trying to make it simpler but its much more confusing then it used to be. They used to have pdf docs with different code samples that explained everything. That said once you have it working its a very solid service - and CIM service is great if you have repeat customers.

Comment: thanks for the help. I agree the documentation is confusing but happy its now working!